# Apache camel multiple dynamic route for single file

Tags: apache-camel

I have a dynamic route which reads and process a file and there could be multiple files. Each route is processing single file at a time. When request comes for different files at the same time there is no issue, as it creates unique URI based on file name. I also need to support parallel request for same file. 
I am getting below exception for parallel request.

Failed to start route MyFileProcessorDynamicRoute because of Multiple consumers for the same endpoint is not allowed.

Is there a way where i can create chaining of route at runtime?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As per your context I am getting to know, you have to use same file(having same name) to be used in different route at same time.

You can achieve by setting flag kind of thing(sequence order in which route has to run) in route were you need to process the same name file. By doing this you cannot start second route without completing first route.

This might tricky but achievable.

Thanks.